# Where should I put my validation code for user input

Tags: c, if-statement

```
if (!strcmp(yn, "y")) {
  isCooked[x] = 1;
  printf("How much %s (in grams) will you cook? ", food[choice - 1]);
} else {
  isCooked[x] = 0;
  printf("How much %s (in grams) will you eat raw? ", food[choice - 1]);
}

scanf("%f", &grams);
userGrams[x] = grams;
```

Where should I put my if-else statement if I want to control the user input of grams? I want to put restrictions on my program, like the user should only input minmimum of 20g and the maximum of 200g.

Comment: After you read the input but before you assign it to `userGrams[x]` would seem like a logical place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `while` loop and an `if`statement -

```
while(scanf("%f", &grams)==1){           // loop until scanf returns 1 
    if(grams>=20 && grams<=200){         // validate your input
        userGrams[x] = grams;            //assign value
        break;                           //break out of loop
    } 
   else{
        printf("Invalid Input !! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried adding an else statement but it doesnt loop. i tried adding else{ printf("Invalid input");} it does'nt loop

Comment: @Alphi You don't need `else` statement. Why would you use it ?

Comment: when the user enter a number like 11 i want my program to prompt invalid input until they enter a number that is between 20 and 200 then the loop should stop.

Comment: @Alphi Try this exactly once .